# install iodocs on linux

Tags: linux, node.js, heroku, amazon-ec2, iodocs

I had [this problem](https://github.com/mashery/iodocs/issues/11) initially, so I tried

```
npm install --force
```

It seems to work, with only one warning:

```
npm WARN querystring@0.0.1 package.json: bugs['web'] should probably be bugs['url']
```

But when I try to run it, it gives me:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-136-14-95 iodocs]$ node ./app.js
The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'hashlib'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/iodocs/app.js:37:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
```

I have no idea what to do with it, please shed some light on me.

BTW, I'm trying to install [iodocs](https://github.com/mashery/iodocs) on a Linux 2.6.35.14-97.44.amzn1.x86_64 EC2 instance.

===========================Update================================================

I have also tried to install it on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/), but hit the same problem:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Resolving engine versions
       Using Node.js version: 0.6.12
       Using npm version: 1.0.106
-----> Fetching Node.js binaries
-----> Vendoring node into slug
-----> Installing dependencies with npm
       npm WARN querystring@0.0.1 package.json: bugs['web'] should probably be bugs['url']
       npm ERR! Unsupported
       npm ERR! Not compatible with your version of node/npm: querystring@0.0.1
       npm ERR! Required: {"node":"0.4.x","teleport":">=0.2.0"}
       npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.0.106","node":"0.6.12"}
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-342-ec2
       npm ERR! command "/tmp/node-node-kXeE/bin/node" "/tmp/node-npm-1IT8/cli.js" "install"
       npm ERR! cwd /tmp/build_3mjp7psqka071
       npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
       npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
       npm ERR! code ENOTSUP

       > hashlib@1.0.1 preinstall /tmp/build_3mjp7psqka071/node_modules/hashlib
       > node-waf clean || true; node-waf configure build

       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/build_3mjp7psqka071/npm-debug.log
       npm not ok
       Nothing to clean (project not configured)
       Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
       Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
       Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
       Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
       Checking for g++                         : ok  
       Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc 
       Checking for gcc                         : ok  
       Checking for node path                   : not found 
       Checking for node prefix                 : ok /tmp/node-node-kXeE 
       'configure' finished successfully (0.476s)
       Waf: Entering directory `/tmp/build_3mjp7psqka071/node_modules/hashlib/build'
       [1/6] cc: libhash/md4c.c -> build/Release/libhash/md4c_1.o
       [2/6] cc: libhash/md5c.c -> build/Release/libhash/md5c_1.o
       [3/6] cc: libhash/sha0c.c -> build/Release/libhash/sha0c_1.o
       [4/6] cxx: hashlib.cc -> build/Release/hashlib_2.o
       ../hashlib.cc:14:16: error: ev.h: No such file or directory
       ../hashlib.cc:15:17: error: eio.h: No such file or directory
       ../hashlib.cc:311: error: 'eio_req' was not declared in this scope
       ../hashlib.cc:311: error: 'req' was not declared in this scope
       ../hashlib.cc:312: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
       Waf: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_3mjp7psqka071/node_modules/hashlib/build'
       Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
        {task: cxx hashlib.cc -> hashlib_2.o}
 !     Failed to install dependencies with npm
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same issue exactly.

I think there's a "Pull Request" that might fix this:
https://github.com/mashery/iodocs/pull/14

I'm going to implement it and if it works, will report.

**EDIT:**

I was able to get farther. Here are some things you need to do:

1. implement the pull request linked above
2. in package.json, update your `"express": "2.5.8"` (the version they have 2.4.8. isn't compatible with node.js v1.0.0
3. remove the "hashlib" directory from "iosdocs/node_modules"

`npm install` should now work.

However, if you run `node ./app.js`, I'm getting this error:

> The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar
>   interface. Express server listening on port 3000
>
> node.js:201
>           throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick

**EDIT #2:**

Figured it out! You have to actually run `redis-server` (DUH).

So I did the following:

1. [Download redis 2.4.8 from their site](http://redis.io/download)
2. Follow their instructions in unzipping, building
3. run the server with `src/redis-server`

Bam, NOW run `node ./app.js` and it works!